# Code samples to test IDE color schemes

Tags: visual-studio, ide, color-scheme

I've just recently discovered how many different options we have to configure the colors of Visual Studio 2010.

Jeff Atwood posted on his blog, some years ago, "[Is your IDE hot or not](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html)", where he shows a code sample to test the IDE colors. However, this sample is not very complete, in the sense that Visual Studio provides more customization options than we can test with that code.

So, could you propose a **code sample to be used to test IDE color schemes**, in the most comprehensive possible way? It would be good to have it in different languages, at least all those accepted by VS2010!

Comment: You'll have to specify the language you're using. Different languages have different syntax highlighting options: HTML, C#, C++, Visual Basic, etc. No one language will have every possible syntax highlighting option in use at the same time.

Comment: I think this should be community wiki. It would be valuable to have different code samples that demonstrate most or all of a given language, but I don't think there's a singular "right answer" that can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio there's this site where you can create your own themes: http://studiostyl.es/schemes/create. It provides some sample code that covers everything as far as VS tags are concerned. Though this is taken from the [coding horror link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/is-your-ide-hot-or-not.html) you have mentioned, it has more than it like xml, xaml, html, asp.NET etc.