# "Universal" source code samples/snippets (in different programming languages) for checking IDE/editor syntax highlighting

Tags: coding-style, ide, editor, syntax-highlighting, universal-code

Is there anywhere in Internet such compilation of "universal" example source codes - in different programming languages - for checking if code's syntax highlighting in IDE/editor works good?

Source code samples, which uses every available language's keywords and statements to check if syntax highlighting works well.

It should look like [Octopress "Syntax Highlighting Test"](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/code/test/) test page. But there, in few examples, the language syntax isn't fully utilized, to show full potential to user.

Comment: I found ["Code samples to test IDE color schemes"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038254/code-samples-to-test-ide-color-schemes) topic, but it's almost 3 years old and still has no answer..